# Timeago date format for less than 24h ago only

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

I would like to use the jquery Timeago plugin as a date format. However, when the time ago has exceeded 24h, I would like it to show another format.

I tried to tweak the code, but my skills let me down :/

**EDIT:**

```
var itemDate = '2014-05-17T09:24:17Z';

if(itemDate > 'THAN 24 HOURS')
{
   $('body').append('<div>show normal date like 17.05.2014</div>');
}
else
{
   $('body').append('<time class="timeago" datetime="'+itemDate+'"></time> ');  
   $(".timeago").timeago();
}
```

Comment: What did you try> Can you show that in the question. What other format do you want to use? Can you not just change that with the settings of the Timeago plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a function that check if the date is 24h older or not .. may be something like:

```
function is_older_than_24hours(datetime) {
     var before = new Date(datetime),
         now = new Date();
     return ( ( now - before ) > ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 )  ) ? true : false;
}

// Then you use your usual code

$(function(){

    var itemDate = '2014-05-17T09:24:17Z';

    if(is_older_than_24hours(itemDate)) {

        var d = new Date(itemDate),
            day = ( d.getDate() > 9 ) ? d.getDate() : '0' + d.getDate(),
            month = ( d.getMonth() > 8 ) ? d.getMonth() + 1 : '0' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            year = d.getFullYear();
        $('<div/>', { text: month +'.'+ day +'.'+ year }).appendTo('body');

    } else {

        $('<time/>', { 'class': 'timeago', 'datetime': itemDate })
            .appendTo('body')
            .timeago();
    }

})
```

Comment: You might want to check that the string concat is in the right order. OP wants dd.MM.yyyy (UK) format. Could you just use `{ text: "' + d.toLocaleDateString() + '"'}` when older than 24 hours?